# What is "Current Post" in a form?

Tags: vocabulary

I have a form which I have to fill in.
Therer are the fields name, address, email and current post.

I know what to fill in in name, address and email. But what is current post?

Comment: It means your current position: in other words, your present job title or job function.

Comment: Yeah, it probably means "job".  But it would depend on the context and probably where you are (or where the form is from).  My impression is that the term is more likely to be used for "job" in England -- in the US "position" would be the more likely term, while "post" has a military connotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is [common reference](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=post%20defintion&gbv=2&oq=post%20defintion&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0i10l8j0i22i10i30l2.1125.5469.0.5797.14.13.0.0.0.0.344.1562.2-2j3.5.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..9.5.1562.tX13c6skPW0).

> Another word for your *job* is your *post*.

This word has many meanings, most of which are related to **jobs and mail.**

> A post is position in a company, like manager or clerk.

It could be where you’re stationed in the military, like a base in Afghanistan.

You can post an ad on a bulletin board or an announcement on a web page.

Comment: Ok, but what do I enter, when I studied and graduated, now I am searching for a job. So there is no prior base or prior job role? Just "Graduate"?

Comment: @user107896 - Probably something like "recently graduated from XYZ".  If you're near your school and they have a placement office they would be able to advise you.